# Cost back link tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, cost-path

I am trying to use cost path analysis to create a least cost path from ports around the UK to various offshore locations. To do this I have created a cost raster grid with values of 0 for land and 1 for sea. When I create the back link raster it does not appear as I would expect with most of the direction provided for the land and only horizontal lines for the sea:

[image]

Does any one have any ideas what I am missing?